# JavaEE7 - How can I intercept @TransactionAttribute annotated methods (before, during, after injection points)

Tags: jakarta-ee

For my specific application, I need to intercept methods annotated with @TransactionAttribute in order to run a custom query before anything is changed in the database.

Except, I can't find anything useful in the JavaEE7 documentation. Is this really not possible? This is possible in our previous architecture using Hibernate's Interceptor interface. Does JTA not cover this?

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/Interceptor.html

Specifically, we are looking to implement something similar to `Interceptor.afterTransactionBegins()`

Kind regards.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in JavaEE 7 then these are EJB3.1 beans right? Then just use @Interceptor on the methods, or if they are all the methods in an EJB you can put it at the class level. See [Introduction to EJB Interceptors](http://docs.jboss.org/ejb3/docs/tutorial/1.0.7/html/EJB3_Interceptors.html) for details from the JBOSS docs. Also you can look at the EJB 3.1 specification for details on them. In your Interceptor class you can inject the EntityManager to run your query.

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't cover what I need to accomplish. More specifically, We need to run INSERT/UPDATE queries inside the current transaction, before anything else. This is an audit interception at the database level. The database has triggers that log all changes to a certain table into another audit table.

Comment: In order to log the active application user, Hibernate was used to intercept all transaction.begin() points and INSERT the current user into a temporary table that could be used by the trigger.

Comment: Once we moved to JPA/JTA, Hibernate's interceptor no longer works the same way. I've been looking for ways to do this using @Intercept, but I can't find it. I'd be happy to see an example of how I can intercept JTA events, like transaction BEGIN/COMMIT/ROLLBACK.